# Solution for loading hook modules on riak cluster restart

Tags: path, erlang, load, hook, riak

I have implemented several hooks for riaks which currently reside in modules that are not in the riak path.

Whenever I wish to install the hooks for a specific bucket, I first run load_module to make sure that the riak nodes can call the hooks. The problem is that if one of the nodes goes down and then back up, it will still try to call the hooks, but will not have access to the module.

What is the recommended way to handle this? One idea I thought was modifying ERL_LIBS such that the hooks are included in its path, is this the right approach?

Answer (score 0):

Just put

```
-pz /path/to/hook/module/
```

at the end of the `vm.args` file (it's in `/etc/riak/` on my installation)